# Full screen on single page VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get one sheet to go full page in excel but my script does the whole workbook at the moment.

Can this be done? *Code below*

```
Sub Fullscreen_Activate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. As you see that all the actions you perform are either located in the `Application` object (which is actually Excel) or the `ActiveWindow` object (which is the Excel window). So they will always affect the entire Excel and not only a specific worksheet (therefore these optoins would have to be in the `Worksheet` object).

You cannot switch this for only one worksheet. But you could workarund this by hiding it when a specific worksheet is activated and unhiding them when it gets deactivated.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Put this in the scope of your worksheet you want to hide this stuff.

Note that you will get strange effects if you close Excel when the toolbars are hidden. Next time you open Excel everything is still hidden. So make sure you unhide them before closing Excel.